# How do I abide by the rules of submission of the Annals of Applied Probability?

Tags: formatting, journal

A while ago I wrote a paper in MS Word. In this paper, I found an improvement of a method introduced in the Annals of Applied Probability (AAP). I want to submit an updated version of the paper with a focus on how my work relates to the paper in AAP. However, AAP has guidelines and a zip file (https://vtex-soft.github.io/texsupport.ims-aap/) with instructions on how to structure your document. I am somewhat new to LaTeX and I use Overleaf and I can't figure out how to format the document so as to fulfill the AAP's guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Your question is really vague.  The link you provide has four steps under setup.  Is one of those tripping you up?  Or is there some aspect of the instructions in aap-sample.pdf that you're not understanding?

Comment: I am unsure how to complete step two "Install LaTeX style files (imsart.cls, imsart.sty) in your TeX system or place them in the same directory where your *.tex file is;" and step four "Use the template file aap-template.tex to prepare your manuscript."

Comment: (2) Skip "install" and place those two files in the same directory where you *.tex file is.  (4) Open aap-template.tex in Overleaf, and fill in the blanks.

Comment: @MathematicalDummy: if you’re doing your LaTeX project entirely on Overleaf, then you should upload copies of those two `imsart` files into your Overleaf project; and then as @Teepeemm says, upload a copy of `aap-template.tex`, and follow the directions there, using that file as the main base for your document.